# How to store and then search through CSV in sql?

Tags: mysql, arrays, csv

I know that I can use IN(1,2,3) to select items from an SQL database where their value is either 1, 2 or 3, but what if I have a value in MYSQL which is a string, and is equal to '1,2,3' and I want to select that value. As far as I know I have to do this:

```
SELECT whatever FROM wherever WHERE sqlvariable = '1' OR sqlvariable LIKE '1,%' OR `sqlvariable` LIKE '%,1,%' OR `sqlvariable` LIKE '%,1'
```

which is fine if I want to simulate 'IN' sort of in reverse. But lets say I want to select sqlvariable where it contains either 1 or 2, then I have to do this:

```
SELECT whatever FROM wherever WHERE sqlvariable = '1' OR sqlvariable LIKE '1,%' OR `sqlvariable` LIKE '%,1,%' OR `sqlvariable` LIKE '%,1' OR sqlvariable = '2' OR sqlvariable LIKE '2,%' OR `sqlvariable` LIKE '%,2,%' OR `sqlvariable` LIKE '%,2'
```

Now lets say I use PHP to generate the above queries and I'm looking to find sqlvariable where it contains a 1 2 4 66 34 33 22 44 or 992. It's going to take an awfully long time for this query to run.

I could do a bitwise implementation, but then I'm limited to only having about 60 different items or so which isn't enough.

Is there a faster way to utilize a CSV query like the above in sql? I suppose it's sort of like IN() but in reverse.

Comment: I certainly hope you're not actually storing CSV strings in your SQL database!  And if you are, I hope you can convince your boss or DBA to be a bit smarter and *parse* the .csv file before you *store* it.

Comment: I don't have a boss, I'm just a Canadian man trying to learn sir :P Thanks for your comments though, I am indeed trying to learn a better approach to storing arrays in databases. I know vBulletin forums store for example, permission group information as a string CSV. For instance a permissions variable on a vbulletin forum looks like '1,2,3' where each number represents a different permission group. How should it be done better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your queries using [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT whatever
FROM   wherever
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('1', sqlvariable)
OR     FIND_IN_SET('2', sqlvariable)
```

This however will still require searching every row in the table. It would be better to redesign your database so that CSV formatted data is not required.

---

Update: Your existing design looks something like this:

```
groupname   groupmembers
Group1      1,2,3
Group2      3,4
```

You should change it to something more like this:

```
groupid   groupmember
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         3
2         4
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I redesign my table. I have a table which groups users into different usergroups. To store the list of users which belong to a usergroup right now I have a table with two values, 'groupname', 'groupmembers'. Since sometimes over 100 users can be in groupmembers I'm not sure how to store them other than using CSV and having something like '1,2,3,4,5,6' as the value for groupmembers where each numeric represents a user.